# what do basename, screenname and usetk do? in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

(screenName=None,  baseName=None,  className=’Tk’,  useTk=1)
i tried removing them and it didnt make a difference
i know how class tk works but what about the rest of it? what do they do?

Comment: In what context? On its own, that's not valid syntax. If you're passing it to a function, you should probably let us know *which* function.

Comment: Those appear to be parameters to `Tk.__init__()`.  NONE of those parameters are normally used, you should ignore them.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You will likely never need to use these parameters.

`baseName` and `className` are used to automatically load in some python and/or tcl code when a window is first created. In addition, they are passed along to some library code written in C.

The low-level C code has this to say about baseName:

```
 /* XXX baseName is not used anymore;
 * try getting rid of it. */
```

In tkinter's `__init__.py` file there is a function where `baseName` and `className` are used. Here is the signature and docstring for that function:

```
def readprofile(self, baseName, className):
    """Internal function. It reads BASENAME.tcl and CLASSNAME.tcl into
    the Tcl Interpreter and calls exec on the contents of BASENAME.py and
    CLASSNAME.py if such a file exists in the home directory."""
```

If you have a file named foo.py or foo.tcl in your home directory and you set `baseName` or `className` to "foo", tkinter will automatically use the code in those files.

`useTk` is just a flag to tell the embedded tcl interpreter whether or not to automatically load the tk library. By setting it to false you end up with a Tcl interpreter without the tk library.

I honestly don't see how either of those are particularly useful.

Comment: I think and will probably try to use this functionality to implement a user config.